# Избитый вопрос про отобрание русского языка в JSP странице.)))

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, jsp, utf-8

Подскажите что нужно указать в JSP странице что бы корректно отображать данные в таблице из MySQL!

[image: Как отображаются данные]

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%--<%@ page isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>--%>
<%@ page contentType='text/html; charset=UTF-8'%>
<%@ page pageEncoding='windows-1251'%>


        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%--<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=Windows-1251" %>--%>
<%--<%@ page pageEncoding='windows-1251'%>--%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> First Work Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <spring:url value="/resources/script/js.js" var="js" />
    <%--<spring:url value="/resources/css/first_work_page_for_cabinet.css" var="style" />--%>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/page_for_group_menu.css" var="style" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/normalize.css" var="normalize" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/tableStyle.css" var="tableStyle" />    
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/script/js.js" />"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${style}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${normalize}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${tableStyle}" >    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</head>    
<body>    
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $(function(){    
        // add multiple select / deselect functionality
        $("#selectall").click(function () {
            $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });

        // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
        // and viceversa
        $(".case").click(function(){

            if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
            }    
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
<!-- HEADER -->
<!-- NAVIGATION -->    
<div class="navigate">
    <ul class="navbar cf">

        <li><a href="/registerPerson/showFirstWorkPage">Cabinet</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Groups</a>
            <%--//create controls item for updeting group--%>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">controls</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/group//showFormForUpdate">Update</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/group//showFormForAddGroup">new group</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Category</a>
                    <%--//create controls item for updeting categoty of group--%>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">controls</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/group//showFormForUpdateCategory">Update</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/group//showFormForAddCategory">new</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <%--//create and show new category--%>
                        <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category">
                            <c:if test="${category.main==true}">
                                <li><a href="#"><c:out value="${category.name}"/></a>
                                    <ul>
                                            <%--//show groups if they location in one of the category--%>
                                        <c:forEach items="${groupsList}" var="groups">
                                            <%--//create links for click--%>
                                            <c:url var="takeGroupId" value="/group//takeIdGroup" >
                                                <c:param name="groupId" value="${groups.id}"/>
                                            </c:url>

                                            <c:if test="${groups.categoryGroup.id==category.id}">
                                                <li> <a href="${takeGroupId}"> <c:out value="${groups.name}"/></a></li>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <%--// Empty li--%>
                <li><a href="#">.....</a></li>
                <%--//show new creating groups--%>
                <c:forEach items="${groupsList}" var="groups">
                    <%--// check, if groups don't belongs some of category, the show it--%>
                    <c:if test="${groups.categoryGroup.id==null && groups.main==true}">
                        <%--//create links for click--%>
                        <c:url var="takeGroupId" value="/group//takeIdGroup" >
                            <c:param name="groupId" value="${groups.id}"/>
                        </c:url>

                        <li><a href="${takeGroupId}"><c:out value="${groups.name}"/></a></li>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <%--//close groups menu, and show first level menu items--%>


        <%--//add this functionality to the Instructors Groups--%>
        <li><a href="#">Instructors Groups</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">controls</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/group//showFormForUpdate">Update</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/group//AddGroupToInstructorsForm">new group</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Category</a>
                    <%--//create controls item for updeting categoty of group--%>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">controls</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/group//showFormForUpdateCategory">Update</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/group//showFormForAddCategoryTrainers">new trainers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <%--//create and show new category--%>
                        <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category">
                            <c:if test="${category.main!=true}">
                                <li><a href="#"><c:out value="${category.name}"/></a>
                                    <ul>
                                            <%--//show groups if they location in one of the category--%>
                                        <c:forEach items="${groupsList}" var="groups">
                                            <%--//create links for click--%>
                                            <c:url var="takeGroupId" value="/group//takeIdGroup" >
                                                <c:param name="groupId" value="${groups.id}"/>
                                            </c:url>

                                            <c:if test="${groups.categoryGroup.id.equals(category.id)}">
                                                <li> <a href="${takeGroupId}"> <c:out value="${groups.name}"/></a></li>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <%--// Empty li--%>
                <li><a href="#">.....</a></li>
                <%--//show new creating groups--%>
                <c:forEach items="${groupsList}" var="groups">
                    <%--// check, if groups don't belongs some of category, the show it--%>
                    <c:if test="${groups.categoryGroup.id==null && groups.main!=true}">
                        <%--//create links for click--%>
                        <c:url var="takeGroupId" value="/group//takeIdGroup" >
                            <c:param name="groupId" value="${groups.id}"/>
                        </c:url>

                        <li><a href="${takeGroupId}"><c:out value="${groups.name}"/></a></li>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <%--//close groups menu, and show first level menu items--%>

        <li><a href="#">Statistic</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>

        <li>
            <h4>You in your cabinet</h4>
        </li>

        <li id="out"><a href='<c:url value="/logout"></c:url>' class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign OUT</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>

<!-- MAIN SECTION -->
<main>

    <div class="work_form">

        <input type="button"  value="VK">
        <input type="button"  value="FACEBOOK">
        <input type="button"  value="advertising">

        <div>

            <br/><br/>
            <form action="find" method="post">
                <select name="option">
                    <option value="name"><spring:message code="firstWorkPage.findStudent.name"></spring:message> </option>
                    <option value="surname"><spring:message code="firstWorkPage.findStudent.surname"></spring:message></option>
                    <option value="email"><spring:message code="firstWorkPage.findStudent.email"></spring:message></option>
                    <option value="phone"><spring:message code="firstWorkPage.findStudent.phone"></spring:message></option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="data" name="data">
                <input type="submit" value="найти">
            </form>

        </div>

        <div class="sort_form" >

            <form method="get" action="/registerPerson//sort">
                <select name="option">
                    <option disabled selected><spring:message code="sort.selectSortType"></spring:message> </option>
                    <option value="ageAfterSixteen"><spring:message code="sort.sortByAgeAfter"></spring:message> </option>
                    <option value="ageBeforeSixteen"><spring:message code="sort.sortByAgeBefore"></spring:message> </option>
                    <option value="getUnknownStudent"><spring:message code="sort.getStudentByOnlyUnknownStudent"></spring:message> </option>
                    <option value="allStudent"><spring:message code="sort.sortByAll"></spring:message> </option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="Sort"></spring:message> ">
            </form>    
        </div>    
    </div>    

    <%--// add to  group from overall kist student--%>
    <form:form action="" >    
        <select name="option">
            <option value="">выберите группу</option>
            <c:forEach items="${groupsList}" var="group">
                <c:if test="${group.name!=null}">
                    <option value="${group.name}">
                        <c:out value="${group.name}"/>
                    </option>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>

    </form:form>

    <input type="button" value="add to group">

    <%--// add to trainers group from overall kist student--%>
    <form:form action="" >

        <select name="option">
            <option value="">выберите группу</option>
            <c:forEach items="${groupsList}" var="group">
                <c:if test="${group.name!=null}">
                    <option value="${group.name}">
                        <c:out value="${group.name}"/>
                    </option>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>

    </form:form>

    <input type="button" value="add to Trainers group">



    <%--Table form--%>
    <div class="table form">

        <form method="get" action="delete">
            <input type="hidden" id="txt" name="">
            <input type="button" value="Добавить"
                   onclick="window.location.href='showFormForAdd'; return false;" class="add-button"
            />

            <input type="submit" name="deletee" value="удалить">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Send email
            </button>
            <input type="button" value="Отправить смс">
            <%--<input type="button" value="отправить письмо">--%>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <br/><br/>
    <br/><br/>

    <table border="3"  width="100%"   cellpadding="4" cellpacing="3">
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Фамилия</th>
        <th>Телефон</th>
        <th>почта</th>
        <th>дата рождения</th>
        <th>Возвраст</th>
        <th>должность</th>
        <th>комментарий</th>
        <th>Дата записи</th>
        <th>Группа </th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"></th>

        <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>${student.name}</td>
                <td align="left">${student.surname}</td>
                <td>${student.phone}</td>
                <td>${student.email}</td>
                <td>${student.strBirthday}</td>
                <td>${student.age}</td>
                <td>${student.post}</td>
                <td>${student.comments}</td>
                <td>${student.recordDay}</td>
                <c:forEach items="${student.groups}" var="group">
                    <c:if test="${group.name.equals(chooseGroup)}">
                <td>${group} <input type="radio"></td>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="case", name="case" value="${student.id}"></td>
                <td align="left"></td>
                <td>
                    <!-- construct an "update" link with customer id -->
                    <c:url var="updateLink" value="/registerPerson/showFormForUpdate" >
                        <c:param name="studentId" value="${student.id}"/>
                    </c:url>

                    <!-- display the update link -->
                    <a href="${updateLink}">Редактировать</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>    
    </table>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choose type of email you'd like to send</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="submit" name="send_email" value="Send simple email" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="send_complex_email" value="Send complex email" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>    
    <br><br>
    <br><br>    
    </div>    
</main>    

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</footer>
<!-- /FOOTER -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Откройте эту страницу в хроме, далее значок настроек -> дополнительные инструменты -> кодировка -> юникод (ютф-8). Помогает?

Comment: MrFylypenko

Нет не помогло там уже стоить UTF-8

Comment: Добавь для воспроизведения минимальный код jsp страницы и код как передаешь данные в jsp страницу.

Comment: Добавил еще кода

Comment: https://github.com/ArtyrGetman/platfor_sport/blob/verlamov/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/A_small_fitness_first_work_Page.jsp


GitHub

Comment: что за ide? в настройках редактора ide надо указать utf-8

Comment: Intellij Да там указано UTF-8

Comment: Сервер Tomcat 8.0.33

Comment: Запустил этот проект, у меня все отображается как надо. Проверь что хранится в БД. И какая кодировка использовалась при создании БД? Если не ` utf8_general_ci` то пересоздай с этим  параметром.

Comment: Кажется понял у меня со страницы в БД передаются кракозяблы((((

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение по Вашему проекту ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051264/6752984)):

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    

                //другие действия с http

                CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
                filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
                filter.setForceEncoding(true);
                http.addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);    
        }
}
```

У Вас первым используется `CsrfFilter`, а необходимо, что бы первым использовался `CharacterEncodingFilter`, приведенный код это решает.

К тому же у класса `Initializer` нет метода `getServletFilter`, а есть метод `getServletFilters`, и он уже лишний, как и фильтр в `web.xml`.